Ergodic hypothesis variation by Landau & Lifshitz
I'd like some help in substantiating a claim in Landau & Lifshitz's Statistical Physics. As explained in this Physics SE post, the authors attempt at sidestepping the ergodic hypothesis by considering quasi-closed subsystems of closed macroscopic systems. The conclusion arrived at in the discussion of said post was that they seem to want to grant credibility to the ergodic hypothesis, by invoking the complex interactions that such a subsystem has with the rest of the system. I wanted to put this in terms of more precise and modern mathematics; specifically, I'm looking for a result in ergodic theory that substantiated this claim (even if it has to impose further restrictions on Landau's assumptions.
Let me try to extract the assumptions from the text. We assume that the dynamical system is a Hamiltonian system. I don't know what to make of Landau's definition that

A closed system is one which doesn't interact with any other systems

Maybe he just means that the system's Hamiltonian completely specifies the dynamics. Furthermore, its phase space is trivial, isomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^s$.
Next, he defines

A subsystem is a part of the system that, although macroscopic, is small compared to it

I doubt this sweetspot notion of size can be given a precise meaning. Additionally, it's not clear what he means by "part", if a subset, a submanifold or only a vector subspace of phase space.
Finally, the authors state that, given such a subsystem, and any block in phase space, there exists a sufficiently long time $T$ such that the orbit of the subsystem will have crossed that block (many times). They then go on to define a probability distribution based on the ratio of the total time that the subsystem spends in a given block of phase space, in the limit.
I have skimmed over the important theorems in ergodic theory's wikipedia page, but because there's this additional caveat of the system-subsystem deal, I couldn't ascertain if those theorems applied here. I also expect that, if such a theorem exists, it probably won't apply as Landau intends to use it (e.g, applying almost everywhere w.r.t to the Lebesgue measure of the phase space insteand of for any block). I know that Physics is sometimes hard to fit in some rigorous and precise mathematical framework, but I hope I made clear the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Hm... Fix a flow $\varphi^t : X \rightarrow X$. The first definition to me seems like a statement that $\varphi^t(X) \subseteq X$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (in other words, $X$ is an invariant set). A subsystem to me seems like a subset which is invariant under the flow as well (or rather, the flow restricted to such a subset). If we have a notion of size via measure, then the next definition could be saying that either an invariant set is essentially (with respect to measure) the whole set or it is nothing, which matches the definition of ergodic.

Finally, the last claim seems to just be the Birkhoff ergodic theorem for flows, where you take the function $f$ to be the characteristic function of a "block." I am no expert in physics (which may be obvious from the above), so take all of this with a grain of salt.
This might be a helpful resource: https://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/publication/docs/lecturenotes16-hasselblatt.pdf

You could have asked what may be the rigorous mathematics behind this initial and on purpose nonrigorous motivation of the book by Landau and Lifshitz. But you are asking for a mathematical clarification of nonmathematical statements by someone else, which perhaps is not so effective (but it may be me).

@JohnB won't the answers to both of those be the same? At the end of the day, I want to cast these statements in the form of rigorous theorems and propositions. That means I have to interpret what their loose statements means precisely

As I mentioned, you are looking at the initial pages of the book, which are written on purpose without rigor. All that you ask has the canonical answers of ergodic theory and of the thermodynamic formalism (of mathematics). You just need to study both, but it is a lot, it really depends on what you already know. Perhaps you would benefit from looking at https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210267
